# Logitech G hub lua script

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)

function OnEvent(event, arg)
    --OutputLogMessage("Event: "..event.." Arg: "..arg.."\n")
  if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 11) then
    repeat
      PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
      Sleep(1,2)
    until not MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED("11")
  end  
end
```

I did this, but an error appears on the first line, but I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There are two mistakes:

- `Sleep(1,2)` is incorrect:
  `Sleep` expects a single argument - an integer amount of milliseconds.
  For example, use `Sleep(10)`
- `MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED("11")` is unknown function

If you want to determine whether button #11 is down:

1. Assign a command "Back" to the mouse button #11 in the user interface of G Hub;
2. Use `IsMouseButtonPressed(4)` in the script:

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    --OutputLogMessage("Event: "..event.." Arg: "..arg.."\n")
  if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 11 then
    repeat
      PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
      Sleep(10)
    until not IsMouseButtonPressed(4)
  end  
end
```